# Azure alerts not firing on rule 4xx

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created a AppService on Azure that runs on Tomcat. I'm using metrics for monitoring and set alert rule, that should send me an email, when error 4xx will occur. Nothing happens even though I've created more errors than rule needs to run alert.

[image: Configuration + alert not fired once]

Thanks, Dominik

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot & the reference for [`Metric Definitions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metricdefinitions), it seems to be normal to not happen the event of sending mail, because your alert rule means the count of the `HTTP 4xx` event is greater than or equal to 5 times over the last 5 minutes, not average count per minute. So you can try to increase the threshold value or shorten the period to check the mail sender whether be triggered when the condition satisfied obviously. Meanwhile, if you doubt the alert trigger whether works fine, you can retrieve the logs via [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-cli-samples) or [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-powershell-samples).

Comment: I'm not getting you're answer and I'm running in into the same issue.
I've configured the same type of Alert for server errors in Azure Monitor. My graph shows lots of server errors but I just can't get the Alert to trigger.